# How to stop facebook like/send buttons overlapping in FF and IE when using multiple buttons on one page in hidden divs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a page that includes multiple news articles which can be shown or hidden by clicking on the news titles. You can also access specific articles directly by adding an id variable to the url, which auto opens the relevant article and scrolls the page to it. Each article has a Facebook like/send button at the bottom of it within a fixed sized div (400px by 30px). This works fine on Safari and Chrome but on IE or Firefox the Like/Send buttons for the url matching the page's og:url tag display correctly, but the other ones overlap and only show the top few pixels of the buttons. The ones that don't display are also in divs that are originally hidden so i'm wondering if this has something to do with it?

You can see what i mean at: http://bit.ly/qMPvM9 (on FF and IE none of them work, on Safari and Chrome all of them work).
If you visit http://bit.ly/n73V0s (which is the same page but it opens the specific news article and has the correct og tags in the header) then the open news article (the one with the matching og tags) works correctly on all browsers (but the others still don't work in FF and IE).

FYI i have put an orange background on the containing divs for the buttons to highlight the issue. If anyone could shed any light on why this might be happening i'd be very grateful.